Reading lines in certain interval from a file in python: alternatives to readline()
I realize that how to read lines from a file in interval [start, stop] is a common question, however many of the standard answers don't work well for my data set.
Specifically, I have data files with 500K lines and 100K columns. Each block of 50 rows is a separate data set which I need to read as a block, analyze, and then move on to the next block. Using readlines() to create a data object which I can sample in increments of 50 will not work, because the data objects take up too much memory.
I thought that something like the following would work (for the example below, I created a test file with 150 lines (3 replicates of 50). "myfunction()" is just a placeholder for the processing of each line)
infile = open("test_file", "r")
outfile = open("out_test_file", "w")

for rep in range(0:3):
    to_sample = list(range(rep*50, rep*50+50))
    i = 0
    for line in infile:
        if i in to_sample:
            something_useful = my_function(line)
    i=i+1
    outfile.write(str(something_useful))

 outfile.close()

The script gets me through the first iteration of 50, but then cannot proceed, presumably because the
for line infile

loop doesn't start at the beginning of the file during the next iteration of rep, since it had already read the last line of the infile.
As I stated, if the data files were of manageable size I could just use readlines and then sample the matrix in the desired intervals using the loop over rep and line number, but this isn't feasible for this dataset. What would be an efficient alternative?

I don't see the point of this. You're reading the entire file each time through the inner loop, just ignoring the lines that aren't in the range.

In each iteration of rep in the outer loop, I want to perform an analysis on lines rep50...rep50+50, write the results of analysis of block rep to the file, and then move on and do the same with rep+1. My question is how to do this efficiently without having to use readlines. Additionally, as my code is now written, it doesn't seem to work - because it reads through the file in its entirety during the first iteration of the outer loop, it reads no lines at all in the next rep iteration.

The inner loop reads the entire file. When you repeat the outer loop, there's nothing left in the file to read.
Use a range loop for the inner loop, and call readline().
for _ in range(3):
    for i in range(50):
        line = infile.readline()
        something_useful = my_function(line)
    outfile.write(something_useful)


Thank you, I think this will give me what I need.

If you want to process only certain line numbers, you could do this:
target_lines = range(5, 100) # or whatever lines you want to process
line_number = 0
for line in file:
    line_number += 1
    if line_number in target_lines:
        # process this line

